# Android : Animation image on button

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-layout, button

I would like to know how to make in my android app the resize animation of icon button like the animation of facebook buttons.

For example, when you click the share button, you can see the icon becames bigger and then it returns to it's normal dimensions. How can I do that?

[image] [image]

That is what I mean

Comment: I'd like to know that too:-) Upvoted!